# как передать функцию в массив

Tags: javascript

Есть таск, надо создать функцию которая вернет массив из n элементов заполнение в соответствии с pattern(вторая переменная которую передают в функцию).
Так вот если передавать числа, строки и т.п. то все просто, но так же надо передать функцию, а вот тут уже проблема.

```js
function sequence(n, pattern) {
   let arr = new Array(n);
   arr.fill(pattern)
   return arr
}

sequence(4, arg => arg%2).forEach((func,i) => console.log(func(i)));
```

Вот мой код.

Comment: Какая проблема? У меня никаких проблем не возникло, все работает как надо

Comment: немного поправлю вопрос, нужно не просто передать функцию в массив, а что бы она выполнялась. Например (i) => i%2 что бы возвращала остаток от деления индекса на 2

Comment: Я уже немного поправил ваш вопрос, все работает, остаток от деления индекса в консоли. В чем вопрос ваш?

Comment: спасибо, немного затупил)

Answer (score 3):

Можно написать проверку, является аргумент функцией или нет, и после этого соответствующим образом заполнить массив:

```
function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
 var getType = {};
 return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}

function sequence(n, pattern) {
  let arr = new Array(n);
  if (isFunction(pattern)) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = pattern(i);
    }
  } else {
    arr.fill(pattern)
  }
  return arr
}
```

Либо реализовать более интересными способами, доступными в ES5:

```
function sequence(n, pattern) {
  return Array.apply(null, {length: n}).map(Function.call, Number).map(pattern);
}
```

Или для ES6:

```
function sequence(n, pattern) {
  return Array.from(Array(n).keys()).map(pattern);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все работает, создал масив из 10-ти функций а именно 10-ять твоих функций в массиве, твоей функцией.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: немного поправлю вопрос, нужно не просто передать функцию в массив, а что бы она выполнялась. Например 
    (i) => i%2
что бы возвращала остаток от деления индекса на 2